# How to deploy ASP.NET Core 2.0 to Azure using TFS

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, tfs, azure-web-app-service

I am using Azure to host an **ASP.NET Core 2.0** web app, but can't seem to work out how to get this deployed from **Team Foundation Server**.

With my *Web API* web app I build the project using the *MSBUILD* **/t:Publish,package** parameters. But the **package** parameter is not supported for **ASP.NET Core 2.0** web apps.

When deploying to Azure I need to create the required zip file, and the **package** parameter created this for me. How do I create the zip file for an **ASP.NET Core 2.0** web app? Or is there some other means for deploying an **ASP.NET Core 2.0** web app to Azure using TFS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the **[dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21)** CLI command. It:

> Packs the application and its dependencies into a folder for
>   deployment to a hosting system.

Within the build task where you run the dotnet publish command, you should see the option 
**Zip Published Projects**. Finally you should publish the build artifact (zip) to any location and use it within your release definition.